# Ошибка: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: c#, mysql, база-данных

имеется ИС Фондовая биржа. Собственно курсовая работа, написана не мной, я полный ноль. Проект старый 2013-2014г., написан коряво. Но суть вот в чем. Заявки открываются нормально и на продажу и на покупку, но когда ставишь галочку "Купить по рыночной цене" чтобы исполнить одну из заявок, получаем ошибку. Гуглил, но решения так и не нашел. Помогите пожалуйста, курсовой на днях уже сдавать.
Если нужно будет еще какой-то код прилепить или скрин - скажите.
[Скрипт](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Xy-VeEjxe0PBSdxFMIWzK5yhGDjRj96v/view?usp=sharing)

```cs
if (Convert.ToDecimal(ask_orderTableAdapter1.GetVolumeByPriceIssue(Convert.ToDecimal(ask_orderTableAdapter1.GetPrice(DateTime.Now, Issue)), Issue)) >= volumeUpDown.Value)
{
    ask_orderTableAdapter1.UpdateVolume(Convert.ToInt32(volumeUpDown.Value),Convert.ToInt32(ask_orderTableAdapter1.GetIDByPriceIssue(Convert.ToDecimal(ask_orderTableAdapter1.GetPrice(DateTime.Now, Issue)), Issue)));
    bid_orderTableAdapter1.InsertOrder(Convert.ToInt32(volumeUpDown.Value), Convert.ToDecimal(ask_orderTableAdapter1.GetPrice(DateTime.Now, Issue)), Issue, Trader);

    //ЗДЕСЬ ИСКЛЮЧЕНИЕ
    contractTableAdapter1.InsertContract(Convert.ToInt32(volumeUpDown.Value), Convert.ToInt32(bid_orderTableAdapter1.GetLastOrderID()), Convert.ToInt32(ask_orderTableAdapter1.GetIDByPriceIssue(Convert.ToDecimal(bid_orderTableAdapter1.GetPrice(DateTime.Now, Issue)), Issue)));
    traderTableAdapter1.UpdateQuery(-(Convert.ToInt32(bid_orderTableAdapter1.GetVolumeByID(Convert.ToInt32(bid_orderTableAdapter1.GetLastOrderID())))*Convert.ToDecimal(bid_orderTableAdapter1.GetPriceByID((int)bid_orderTableAdapter1.GetLastOrderID()))), Trader);

    bid_orderTableAdapter1.CloseOrder(DateTime.Now, Convert.ToInt32(bid_orderTableAdapter1.GetLastOrderID()));
    if(Convert.ToDecimal(ask_orderTableAdapter1.GetVolumeByPriceIssue(Convert.ToDecimal(ask_orderTableAdapter1.GetPrice(DateTime.Now, Issue)), Issue)) == 0)
    {
        ask_orderTableAdapter1.CloseOrder(DateTime.Now, Convert.ToInt32(ask_orderTableAdapter1.GetIDByPriceIssue(Convert.ToDecimal(ask_orderTableAdapter1.GetPrice(DateTime.Now, Issue)), Issue)));
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам поможет только `cheating` уберите обработку состояния чекбокса так, чтоб независимо от его состояния была покупка не по рыночной цене. Это самое простое и быстрое что вы можете сделать. На такую логическую ошибку вряд ли кто обратит внимание.

Comment: Не получится. Покупка не по рыночной цене - выставляет заявку. Покупка по рыночной цене - исполняет заявку. И то, и то должно работать

Comment: Судя по сообщению об ошибке у вас происходит нарушение ограничения в таблице `contact` по внешнему ключу `Ask_Order_ID`. А конкретнее почему и как это происходит нужно работать с отладкой и видеть ваш код. Короче нужно открывать ваш код в студии, ставить точки останова, запускать отладку смотреть значения переменных и ... Да, и код ужасен это точно.

Comment: Пишет не допустимый термин "" в выражении

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была решена добавлением задержки между запросами:

```
bid_orderTableAdapter1.InsertOrder(Convert.ToInt32(volumeUpD own.Value), Convert.ToDecimal(ask_orderTableAdapter1.GetPrice(DateTime.N ow, Issue)), Issue, Trader);
await Task.Delay(1000);
contractTableAdapter1.InsertContract(Convert.ToInt32(volumeU pDown.Value), Convert.ToInt32(bid_orderTableAdapter1.GetLastOrderID()), Convert.ToInt32(ask_orderTableAdapter1.GetIDByPriceIssue(Con vert.ToDecimal(bid_orderTableAdapter1.GetPrice(DateTime.Now, Issue)), Issue)));
```